# Как реализовать просмотр сквозь одежду определённой области в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Звучит глупо, понимаю. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении например круга на одежду, она просвечивалась, но только в области этого круга. Одежда отрисовывается через Skinned Mesh Renderer, я не могу понять как это можно реализовать. Подскажите кто-нибудь, вообще не понимаю куда рыть

Comment: [Stencil buffer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlj2-fnFvF4)

Comment: Вы уверены, что стоит оставлять *такую* ссылку?